# Lie transformation applied to Poisson brackets

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given the following Lie transformation:

$$
\exp(\lbrace H,  \cdot \rbrace):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lbrace H,  \cdot \rbrace)^n}{n!}
$$
and apply it to a Poisson Bracket $\lbrace g_1,  g_2 \rbrace$.
I would like to show that
$$
\exp(\lbrace H, \lbrace g_1,  g_2 \rbrace\rbrace)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lbrace H,  \lbrace g_1,  g_2 \rbrace \rbrace)^n}{n!}=\lbrace \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lbrace H,  g_1\rbrace)^n}{n!}, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lbrace H,  g_2\rbrace)^n}{n!}\rbrace=\lbrace\exp(\lbrace H, g_1\rbrace),\exp(\lbrace H, g_2\rbrace)\rbrace
$$

I am sure this property holds, since I found this here (page 25): http://www.aps.anl.gov/Science/Publications/lsnotes/content/files/APS_1418211.pdf

but I have difficulties in proving this in an elegant way.
Could someone give me a good reference?

Comment: Answered on physics stackexchange